# Regular Expression to reject special characters except slahses?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a RegularExpressionValidator to block all special characters.  Currently my expression is this:

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$"
```

However I would like to allow slashes: (`/`)

I'm new to regular expressions and not sure how to write them.  I've looked around online but don't see one to allow slashes.  Any help?

Comment: just add slashe into the brackets. e.g. `^[0-9a-zA-Z \/]+$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply place the characters that you want to *match* inside of your character class `[]`.

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9/ ]+$"
```

Regular expression:

```
^                   # the beginning of the string

 [a-zA-Z0-9/ ]+     # any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', 
                    # '0' to '9', '/', ' ' (1 or more times)

$                   # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Since you stated you are new to regular expressions, I would begin with this [Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html). For more information about characters inside of a character class, take a look at [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Great thank you!  I appreciate the added information

Comment: This will work, but you don't have to escape the `/`, which is not a special character in regular expressions (unless it's JavaScript).